# how to send an email in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, email

i want to send an email using a asp.net mvc 4 application   i am using this  method

```
     public void send_mail(ProcRec.Models.AccuseReception _objModelMail)
    {

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(_objModelMail.To);
        mail.From = new MailAddress(_objModelMail.From);
        mail.Subject = _objModelMail.Subject;
        string Body = _objModelMail.Body;
        mail.Body = Body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
        ("username", "password");// Enter seders User name and password
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(mail);


    }
```

My  model  :

```
            public class AccuseReception
{


    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }


}
```

controller   :

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

           AccuseReception confermation_mail = new AccuseReception {

            From="xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
            To ="ssssssss@gmail.com",
            Subject ="mail_de confermation",
            Body = "votre demande est enregistrer ",

            };

        send_mail(my_mail);
         }
```

i  get  no error  but the mail is not sending   and   the ModelState is not valid

Comment: Your example is not showing a use of your model... this is quite basic. BTW if you want to easily send more complex html as emails, you can use `Postal`. 
In Postal you build views that are sent as emails:
http://aboutcode.net/postal/

Comment: this how i use my model
  AccuseReception my_mail = new AccuseReception {
                
                From="amhhhhhhhhhh@gmail.com",
                To =candidat.adresse_mail,
                Subject ="mail_de confermation",
                Body = "votre demande est enregistrer , votre code d'identification pour modifier vos informations est ..Merci",
                
                };

Comment: Sauce: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/sourabh_mishra1/sending-an-e-mail-using-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ModelState belongs to a model that is passed to corresponding view/controller.

I see that in your controller you create a new `AccuseReception` so i assume that you are not getting AccuseReception as a model in this controller action.

This is the reason your `ModelState.IsValid` returns false and no mails are sent.

Try something like:

```
 public void SendMail(ProcRec.Models.AccuseReception _objModelMail)
 {
       if(ModelState.IsValid)
       {

           MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
           mail.To.Add(_objModelMail.To);
           mail.From = new MailAddress(_objModelMail.From);
           mail.Subject = _objModelMail.Subject;
           string Body = _objModelMail.Body;
           mail.Body = Body;
           mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
           SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
           smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
           smtp.Port = 587;
           smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
           smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
           ("username", "password");// Enter seders User name and password
           smtp.EnableSsl = true;
           smtp.Send(mail);
        }    
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vb.net example that should work for you. I can't see your model in the example. But that should be enough:

```
Dim smtpClient As New SmtpClient(_ServerHost, _ServerPort)
smtpClient.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(_EmailAddress, _EmailPass, String.Empty)
smtpClient.EnableSsl = True
smtpClient.Timeout = 60000

Dim mailmsg as New MailMessage
mailmsg.Subject = i_Subject
mailmsg.From = New MailAddress(emailAddress, displayName)
mailmsg.To.Clear()
mailmsg.IsBodyHtml = True
mailmsg.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure

' Add email addresses
mailmsg.To.Add("someemail@gmail.com")

mailmsg.Body = SomeBodyHTML

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(mailmsg.Body.Trim) Then
    ' Send message
    smtpClient.Send(mailmsg)
End If
```

BTW if you want to easily send more complex html as emails, you can use Postal. In Postal you build views that are sent as emails:

[aboutcode.net/postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal)